How to handle pagination when getting all results with Facebook Ads PHP SDK?
I'm working with the Facebook Ads API in PHP, and I'm using the getInsights() method to fetch ad insights. However, it only returns the first 25 results, and I understand that I need to handle pagination to retrieve the full dataset. The getInsights() method returns a cursor-like object, but I’m not sure how to correctly handle pagination to fetch all pages of results?
$account = new AdAccount('act_' . $accountId);

$params = [
    'time_range' => ['since' => '2023-09-01', 'until' => '2023-09-30'],
    'level' => 'adset'
];

$fields = [
    AdsInsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
    AdsInsightsFields::ADSET_ID,
    AdsInsightsFields::ADSET_NAME,
    AdsInsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
    AdsInsightsFields::CLICKS,
    AdsInsightsFields::SPEND
];

$insights = $account->getInsights($fields, $params);

// How do I handle pagination to fetch all results?

How can I iterate through all pages of results using the pagination methods provided by the API? Specifically, I’m unclear on how the next() method works and how to properly check for more results.
The readme/documentation isn't too clear https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-business-sdk#cursors
// Fetch the next page
$cursor->fetchAfter();
// New Objects will be appended to the cursor

What do I do after that? The foreach again?

Seems to do the job
$insights = $account->getInsights( // ..
$insights->setDefaultUseImplicitFetch(true);

while ($insights->valid()) {
  $insight = $insights->current();
  $insightData = $insight->getData();

  $insights->next();
}

